# Input from user without the <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

i need to get an input from user, for instance his name, but the user won't be able to edit his name, like in a text box. This is what i'm using right now:

```
<input id="number_input" type="text" size="12" maxlength="19" />
```

In order to write or edit his name the user will use already existing buttons. Just like in a calculator. How can i achieve this in html??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably consider using  this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

[DEMO HERE](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/378_jqueryKeyboard/demo/index.html)

Comment: Exactly what the OP needs. Something like on screen keyboard